# How to use GDB to monitor two different variables with the same name

Tags: gdb

I need to use GDB to monitor two different variables with the same name, one of which is a global variable, while the other is a local variable. Any solution?

Comment: If one is global and one is local, it seems like they are two different variables. Please provide an example of what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
int foo;

void bar()
{
  foo++;
}

int main()
{
  int foo;
  for (foo = 0; foo < 5; foo++) {
    bar();
  }
  return 0;
}

gcc -g t.c
gdb -q ./a.out

(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x40050a: file t.c, line 11.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:11
11    for (foo = 0; foo < 5; foo++) {
(gdb) p &foo
$1 = (int *) 0x7fffffffdccc
(gdb) watch -l foo
Hardware watchpoint 2: -location foo
```

Note: above watch is set on local `foo`.

```
(gdb) p &::foo
$2 = (int *) 0x60103c <foo>
(gdb) watch -l ::foo
Hardware watchpoint 3: -location ::foo
```

Note: above watch is set on global `foo`.

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 3: -location ::foo
```

Global `foo` has been modufied inside `bar()`.

```
Old value = 0
New value = 1
bar () at t.c:6
6   }
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 2: -location foo
```

Local `foo` has been modified inside `main`:

```
Old value = 0
New value = 1
0x0000000000400521 in main () at t.c:11
11    for (foo = 0; foo < 5; foo++) {
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 3: -location ::foo

Old value = 1
New value = 2
bar () at t.c:6
6   }
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 2: -location foo

Old value = 1
New value = 2
0x0000000000400521 in main () at t.c:11
11    for (foo = 0; foo < 5; foo++) {
```

... etc.